# Jquery/ASP.NET project doesn't work properly, virtually identical jsfiddle works as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've got a JQuery/ASP.NET project that isn't working as expected, but the virtually identical code in JSFiddle works as expected.  I'm simply passing some text as a variable into an alert() which should pop up when you click "Click Me" on the form.  Eventually I'll be using an AJAX call to pass it back to the code behind, but first things first, so ignore the AJAX calls & functions, I'm not using those yet.

Here's the JS (referenced in the ASP below as "OnlineRMA.js":

```
$("#button").on('click', function () {
var test = $("#SBE_Services").val();
alert(test);
//asyncServerCall(test);
}); 

function asyncServerCall(userid) {
$.ajax
(
    {
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetData',
        type: "POST",
        data: "{'userid':" + userid + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    }
);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#SBE_Services").dropdownchecklist();
});
```

Here's the ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="JqueryAjaxExample.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/onlinerma.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <label for="SBE_services">Requested Services</label>
        <select id="SBE_Services" multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="Calibration">
                <option>Temperature</option>
                <option>Conductivity</option>
                <option>Pressure</option>
                <option>Dissolved Oxygen</option>
                <option>pH</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Repairs">
                <option>O-Ring Replacement &amp; Inspection</option>
                <option>Hydrostatic Test</option>
                <option>Diagnose &amp; Repair Problems</option>
                <option>Replace Anti-Foulant Devices</option>
                <option>Download Data From Instrument</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Third Party Sensors">
                <option>Fluorometer</option>
                <option>Transmissometer</option>
                <option>Turbidity</option>
                <option>SUNA</option>
                <option>PAR</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, here's [the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delliottg/EWX6F/)

On the fiddle, click to the right of "Requested Services" and choose a few (doesn't matter how many as long as you've chosen at least one, there's no error handling yet if you don't).  Then click "Click Me".  You should get a JS Alert listing your choices.  In the ASP project this doesn't work, and I don't understand why.  The only difference is a slightly customized JQuery-UI, but I don't think this is the issue.  The dropdownchecklist stuff is working so that tells me that it's seeing the JS in the external file, I just don't know why I'm not getting the JS Alert.

Just as a sanity check, I built an HTML-only page with all the same stuff in it (basically pulled out the first line and removed any "runat" statements), I also pointed to the CDN versions of JQuery & JQuery-UI instead of pointing to my local ones, and I'm getting the same behavior, no alert.  That tells me it's not an ASP issue, probably not a JQuery issue, it's something else I'm missing.  I even changed the alert to:
`alert("test");` to no avail.  What am I missing?  Maybe I've got a path mis-configured?  This is driving me nuts!

Edit:  This morning I rebuilt the HTML file using the CDN references from JQuery, and now it works as expected.  Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/onlinerma.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">
    <div>
        <label for="SBE_services">Requested Services</label>
        <select id="SBE_Services" multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="Calibration">
                <option>Temperature</option>
                <option>Conductivity</option>
                <option>Pressure</option>
                <option>Dissolved Oxygen</option>
                <option>pH</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Repairs">
                <option>O-Ring Replacement &amp; Inspection</option>
                <option>Hydrostatic Test</option>
                <option>Diagnose &amp; Repair Problems</option>
                <option>Replace Anti-Foulant Devices</option>
                <option>Download Data From Instrument</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Third Party Sensors">
                <option>Fluorometer</option>
                <option>Transmissometer</option>
                <option>Turbidity</option>
                <option>SUNA</option>
                <option>PAR</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click me" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also built another page with just a button that uses pure JS instead of JQuery, it worked perfectly inside an ASP.NET page, so it's something to do with JQuery or JQuery-UI, or maybe the dropdownchecklist.  When I added a JQuery selector instead of a function call, it stopped working.  I'll start trying to isolate which of the JQ stuff is the culprit.

Edit 2:

I build a barebones ASP.NET project with just a simple input button and corresponding JQuery selector to respond to the `onclick` event so anyone who wants to help figure this out has a simple way of doing so.  Start a new ASP.NET project, accept the default names, add a web page to the project (also accepting default name), then make it the start page.  Here's the code for the page, I've changed no other files:

Edit 3 incorporating John's suggestion in the answer, and it now works:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1-vsdoc.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").on('click', function() {
        alert("You clicked the button");
    });
});
</script>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

All of the JQuery related `<script>` calls are to various CDN resources so you don't need to download anything to make this work.  Someone else must have run into this before, but it's surprisingly hard to find anything on the web that speaks to this specific problem.

Comment: Is there a reason your script tags are outside your 'html' and 'head' tags?

Comment: Try adding an error: function(jqXHR,status,error){alert('status='+status+', error='+error)} and see if it is failing and if so, what the error is.

Comment: @JordanRynard I tried moving them inside as you suggested, no change in behavior.  I tried adding an error trap as Ron suggested, same thing.  So I wrote a pure JS function to pop up the alert and it worked perfectly, so then I added a JQuery selector `$(#"button").onclick(function() { alert("Alert works!")}` and it stopped working, so the problem lies in the JQuery interaction with ASP.NET somewhere.  The HTML page with full blown JQuery works as expected, so it's ASP.NET somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code:

```
$("#button").on('click', function () {
var test = $("#SBE_Services").val();
alert(test);
//asyncServerCall(test);
});
```

should be inside your $(document).ready(function(){});

like so:.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button").on('click', function () {
    var test = $("#SBE_Services").val();
    alert(test);
    //asyncServerCall(test);
    }); 


    $("#SBE_Services").dropdownchecklist();
});
```

Comment: John, thanks for the try, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.  I've moved the code inside the `$(document).ready(function()...` call (and that works as expected in the fiddle as well as the HTML, so it's seemingly perfectly valid), but I still get the same behavior with the ASP.NET project, nothing happens when I click the button other than the DDCL collapsing.

Comment: what browser are you using, are there any errors in the error console?

Comment: another thing, you said you pulled out all the runat='server' from your elements, do you have a runat=server on the button or the select?  if so, the problem might be the id mangling in asp.net.

Comment: John, as it turns out your original suggestion does work, I tried it on my simple ASP.NET project listed above (which I'll correct here shortly), and when I placed the code inside the `<script>` tags, VS2010 noticed that I was missing a closing `}`, which it never saw on the .JS page.  Once I got that running, I carefully when through the .JS page in the original project and found the same missing closing curly brace, added it, and voila, I now have a working proof of concept.  Thanks!